# Designing packet structure of a protocol

Tags: data-structures

I'm writing a small manual for our self-developed protocol.

To show the packet structure we like to include a table like it's shown on this Wikipedia page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure

Is there any prebuilt library for this purpose or should it be implemented by myself?

Comment: You might have a look to the [`bytefield`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bytefield) package.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the [`bytefield`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bytefield) package, developed exactly with the purpose of drawing protocol packet structures.

An example taken from the manual:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{bytefield}


\begin{document}

    \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.1em]{32}
        \bitheader{0-31} \\
        \begin{rightwordgroup}{RTP \\  Header}
            \bitbox{2}{V=2} & \bitbox{1}{P} & \bitbox{1}{X}
            & \bitbox{4}{CC} & \bitbox{1}{M} & \bitbox{7}{PT}
            & \bitbox{16}{sequence number} \\
            \bitbox{32}{timestamp}
        \end{rightwordgroup} \\
        \bitbox{32}{synchronization source (SSRC) identifier} \\
        \wordbox[tlr]{1}{contributing source (CSRC) identifiers} \\
        \wordbox[blr]{1}{$\cdots$} \\
        \begin{rightwordgroup}{RTP \\ Payload}
            \wordbox[tlr]{3}{MPEG-4 Visual stream (byte aligned)} \\
            \bitbox[blr]{16}{}
            & \bitbox{16}{\dots\emph{optional} RTP padding}
        \end{rightwordgroup}
    \end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]